# I'm a beginner modeling a mug. Weird thing happening when I extrude the cylinder to create the hollow part

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm modeling this mug as a part of a beginner tutorial
[image: Ikea Mug]
I created a concentric circle using the `inset`tool on top to represent the width of the mug.
When I select the inner face on top and extrude it down to the bottom, the  iner surface bulges out. I'm assuming this is due to the top face being wider than the bottom but I'm not sure how to fix that.
Here's my model :
[image: Wonky mug]

Comment: There is nothing weird about it, the inside of your cup is protruding through the outside shell because you made it wider

Answer (score 1):

Just scale the face down until it's not protruding anymore.
.